# Logistic Regression: TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am trying to perform a logistic regression and I am getting the Type Error:
'cannot perform reduce with flexible type'. I checked an all my variables are integers. 
I am getting the error at this line:

```
"logit_model=sm.Logit(y,X)"
```

and something here:

```
lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in _ptp(a, axis, out, keepdims)
151 def _ptp(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
152     return um.subtract(
```

--> 153         umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims),
    154         umr_minimum(a, axis, None, None, keepdims),
    155         out

It does not feel like the series in the dataset are actually 'flexible', and since I converted them to integers, there are no Nans or infs.

Thank you for your help,

Lili

Comment: Just to clarify, the tag is for `scikit-learn`, but since you are calling `sm.Logit()`, do you by any chance mean `statsmodels`?